# Is there any function that has the series expansion $x+x^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{\frac{1}{3}}+\cdots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3+ \cdots$$

Is there a $f(x)$ that has the series of $n$th roots?

$$f(x)= x+x^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{\frac{1}{3}}+ \cdots$$

Wolfram Alpha seemed to not understand my input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your series doesn't converge because as Hagen von Eitzen said $\sqrt[n]x\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Though if you consider:

$$g(x)=(\sum_{k=1}^nx^{1/k})-n-\ln(x)\ln(n)$$

As $n\to\infty$ this does indeed converge and has the alternate series expansion:

$$g(x)=\gamma\ln(x)+\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac{\zeta(m)}{m!}\ln(x)^m$$

Where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^s}$.

Similar looking series also crop up in expansions for prime counting functions. For example the Von Mangoldt function is usually used as a proxy for counting primes due to it's "nice" arithmetic nature and once an expression has been obtained for a sum involving the Mangoldt function. Inverting it back into a series involving only primes requires introducing many integer roots.

For instance note the two very good asymptotic approximations for the prime counting function $\pi$ and the first Chebyshev function $\vartheta$ given by these similar looking series:

$$\sum_{p\leq x}1=\pi(x)\sim \sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(x)^m}{mm!\zeta(m+1)}$$
$$\sum_{p\leq x}\ln(p)=\vartheta(x)\sim \sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac{\ln(x)^m}{m!\zeta(m)}$$

Which appear as a result of their inversions with other functions related to the Mangoldt function:

$$\Pi(x)=\pi(x)+\frac{1}{2}\pi(x^{1/2})+\frac{1}{3}\pi(x^{1/3})+\frac{1}{4}\pi(x^{1/4})+\frac{1}{5}\pi(x^{1/5})+\dots$$

$$\psi(x)=\vartheta(x)+\vartheta(x^{1/2})+\vartheta(x^{1/3})+\vartheta(x^{1/4})+\vartheta(x^{1/5})+\vartheta(x^{1/6})+\dots$$

Where we have that:

$$\Pi(x)=\sum_{2\leq n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{\ln(n)}$$
$$\psi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)$$

With $\Lambda$ the Von Mangoldt function appearing in the above partial sums.

Though I assume by your MSE picture and name that your probably already familiar with a lot of this stuff, as the error terms in the series' can be written as sums over zeros of the zeta function.

Comment: @anon Yea my bad didn't notice that, I changed it so it works now.

Comment: @Ethan Yes, I am somewhat familiar with the zeta function; no formal education on it...yet. Thanks for your informative answer!

Answer (score 15):

For $x>0$ we have $\sqrt[n]x\to 1$ hence the series cannot converge

Comment: What's more, you can show with some effort that for large $n$, $\sqrt[n]{x}\approx 1+\frac Cn$ for some $C$, so trying to sum $\left(\sqrt[n]{x}-1\right)$ doesn't turn out any better.

Comment: @RahulNarain It has to, by the usual alternating series convergence theorems.  Or do you mean that it converges to a 'known' function of $x$?

Comment: @Steven: Not really sure what my point was. I had forgotten the usual theorems. It's been a while since I did real analysis...

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly an answer... but I find the question intriguing and totally want to know if it's been studied before.  [Who cares if it doesn't converge](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/02/04/science/in-the-end-it-all-adds-up-to.html?_r=0)?

What is interesting about your series is that because the denominators of the exponents are not bounded, it is not a [Puiseux series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series), nor even a [Hahn series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_series) (which I had never heard of) because the set of exponents is not well-ordered!

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0,~x+x^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{\frac{1}{3}}+...$ can't converges since $x^{\frac{1}{n}}\to1.$ Neither does it for $x<0$ since $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is undefined then. So the only possibility is the trivial one: $$f:\{0\}\to\mathbb R:0\mapsto 0$$